# How can I remove vulnerabilities, everytime I run the command npm install highcharts --save

Tags: angular, installation, cmd, highcharts

When I do the command npm install highcharts --save I always have this result:
How can I make it 0 vulnerabilities?

```
C:\Users\bagal\Desktop\FirstChart>npm install highcharts --save

added 1 package, removed 1 package, and audited 901 packages in 1m

92 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

6 vulnerabilities (3 low, 3 moderate)

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Comment: It says it right there in the message `To address all issues (including breaking changes), run: npm audit fix --force`.

Comment: Sorry for a late reply, my connection was interrupted. Btw, after running this command `npm audit fix --force`  I still have the same result. Should I run it until it remove all vulnerabilities?

Comment: Are you using this instruction from [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-angularc) to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from running npm audit fix as the prompt suggests, there is nothing you can really do. NPM is a package manager, meaning all it does is just download the needed packages to make your project work, if a particular package has a vulnerability it is up to the creator of the package to fix it.